# How to stop Do Not Disturb turning on every day at midnight?

Tags: settings, volume, do-not-disturb

Every day at 00:00 my phone goes into Do Not Disturb mode. I have turned off Do Not Disturb in all settings. I have tried with scheduled Do Not Disturb and with the schedule turned off.

[image]

[image]

No matter what, it turns on every day at 00:00 without my permission.

**How do I stop this?**

Comment: look in Settings - Apps - Configure - Special Access - Do not disturb access, or in Settings - Apps - Configure - App permissions - Phone, or in Settings - Accessibility - Services for third party Apps like Tasker/Macrodroid/Automate

Comment: In `Settings - Apps - Configure - [Menu] - Do not disturb access` "Digital wellbeing" asks me for overrride then won't let me do it even after clicking "OK" (despite "Digital wellbeing" not existing as an app on my phone).

Comment: `adb shell pm uninstall com.google.android.apps.wellbeing`

Comment: Is there really no non-`adb` method?

Comment: you can install terminal emulator app and type `pm uninstall com.google.android.apps.wellbeing` or install any third party app manager where you can freeze packages

Comment: `Failure calling service package: Failed transaction`  I can see it if I show system apps but only force close not uninstall.

Comment: I don't even think it's a google app at all it looks more like a Samsung one. Apparently I need root for a terminal emulator which is not possible.

Comment: if not working from terminal emulator, try it from adb shell it has different permissions `pm disable --user 0 com.google.android.apps.wellbeing` will freeze the package. If you know which app causes this just clear data from app manager