# Prevent my phone from leaving "Do not disturb" and "silence"

Tags: volume-control, do-not-disturb

I have a similar problem to [How to stop Do Not Disturb turning on every day at midnight?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215541/how-to-stop-do-not-disturb-turning-on-every-day-at-midnight)

I set my "Do not disturb" on to stay on "until you turn off". Nonetheless, at random times, it turns off by itself.
I also have the same issue with silencing my audio. Usually at the same time as the "do not disturb" turns off, "silence" turns off.

Do you know what other settings might be controlling the state of "do not disturb" or the volume?

Comment: So, let me see if I understood - you want to keep your phone silenced until you manually turn DnD off, right? If you manually set DnD, will it turn off automatically, let's say, in the morning?

Comment: That's correct. And I don't want that to happen